# Azure AD signature mismatch with Spring Security OAuth

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I am using the new Spring Security OAuth 2.2.1 after it fixed a [NullPointerException](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/pull/1130) that occurred during Azure AD authentication.

I have set up my application for scopes `User.Read,email,profile,openid`. For now, I only need to experiment with user name and email attributes. My application will allow people from a specific organization to log in to a corporate portal.

I have configured Spring Security to use the following

```
oauth.authorizationUri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
oauth.accessTokenUri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
oauth.jwkStore=https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/discovery/v2.0/keys
<oauth2:rest-template id="office365OAuthRestTemplate" resource="office365AuthenticationSource" />

<b:bean id="preAuthFilter_oAuth2Office365ClientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg value="/auth/office365" />
    <b:property name="restTemplate" ref="office365OAuthRestTemplate" />
    <b:property name="tokenServices">
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
            <b:property name="tokenStore">
                <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkTokenStore">
                    <b:constructor-arg value="${oauth.jwkStore}" />
                </b:bean>
            </b:property>
        </b:bean>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>

<oauth2:resource id="office365AuthenticationSource" client-id="${oauth.appId}" client-secret="${oauth.appSecret}" type="authorization_code"
    authentication-scheme="form" client-authentication-scheme="form" use-current-uri="true" user-authorization-uri="${oauth.authorizationUri}" access-token-uri="${oauth.accessTokenUri}"
    scope="${oauth.scopes}" pre-established-redirect-uri="${oauth.redirectUri}" />
```

When I invoke the OAuth endpoint I am redirected to Office 365 login page, then I use my organization account to log in and grant consent.

When control returns to the application Spring throws an exception stating that the signature is invalid

```
org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.InvalidSignatureException: RSA Signature did not match content
    at org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaVerifier.verify(RsaVerifier.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtImpl.verifySignature(JwtHelper.java:287)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkVerifyingJwtAccessTokenConverter.decode(JwkVerifyingJwtAccessTokenConverter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.convertAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.readAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkTokenStore.readAccessToken(JwkTokenStore.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication(DefaultTokenServices.java:229)
```

I have tried to debug Spring internally and at the point of verifying the token I had this:

```
Jwt decoded token from Azure AD:
 {"typ":"JWT","nonce":"AQABAAAAAABHh4kmS_aKT5XrjzxRAtHzrO_Mx4UxOY-L-GziwhdDCsXsWvff37te1VyDQVbwKv1kShPXBDzdhfLvkcDvPYtzjAbjqda03Vymwqo37wnzgyAA","alg":"RS256","x5t":"x478xyOplsM1H7NXk7Sx17x1upc","kid":"x478xyOplsM1H7NXk7Sx17x1upc"} {"aud":"https://graph.microsoft.com","iss":"https://sts.windows.net/e5bba1bc-6831-4138-b926-6d70d24c0a13/","iat":1513770650,"nbf":1513770650,"exp":1513774550,"acr":"1","aio":"Y2NgYOgPDvdVbZ08s2up4dL3OyvMNdWZ1Xg/tpTlcuxe/cdmXzYA",--------------,"ver":"1.0"} [256 crypto bytes]

Key to verify against (stored in SignatureVerifier)
     exponent: AQAB
     keyId: x478xyOplsM1H7NXk7Sx17x1upc
     modulus: w-SDUgtC2nAU8-qIEFXfBd3z0qgNbk0D8OIFA9lgg17_-DqB2s5ydPomNLmaee1dRGy-ULxrxA80J5f3O7GLQy8SheO7JE4nCcCFnIeaRZCHznSlSIVMgIK4MlcGsyIx0th95on0LRICnDY6EOIIQPvseHejG4_j2ihLkzL3r9vc8zvooL8ZO_hUznJ085em9SkvMyhq9B04ZQKNRhTbP23AJheYIu3A6I1YVb3Kqh_q1IDERlF7OrQeL2pToMXQwinRNPoUq9QLy6LilxhfuFnpT3I5clUHT7odd2kZDjazKm-grWHyZxFEsDkB3-jHpggnf2PS0mbnL7gffs28dQ
```

Verifier instance : SunRsaSign version 1.8

The key information contained in the JWT token matches the key the SignatureVerifier is loading. The key looks also legit as I can find them on https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/discovery/v2.0/keys

What is wrong in my Spring configuration?